# Multiline Edit in VS Code not working

Tags: editor, visual-studio-code

alt + left click or ctrl+alt_left click is suppose to enable multi linje edit in VScode but why is it not working, did they change the way it is done?

Comment: Checked in the latest insider build: `ALT+Left click` doesn't work in a reliable way. Sometimes it's working and sometimes not. You shoul create an issue here https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues

Comment: As Wosi stated, you should report the issue, **but only after you've checked to see that one hasn't already been created for this**.

Comment: Is it working on you VS code?

Comment: @MezzanineLearner what OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Linux